# WPF Textbox Validation on Startup

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

In my WPF project I have added validation to a string property named '**Address**' as follows:

```
            <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplateSilverlightStyle}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Address" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                         ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <vd:EmptyStringValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" /> 
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

The custom validation rule, EmptyStringValidation, contains the following simple Validate method:

```
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {

        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)value))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Its empty");
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Field cannot be empty");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
```

My issue is, when starting the project up, the Address TextBox is not showing the red outline to indicate there is an error.

I know the custom empty string rule **is** executing, as I set up a debug to print out if the string is empty.

If I type content into the address textbox, and then remove it, to leave an empty textbox, the red outline then appears.

How can I get this outline to appear on startup, or at least on tabbing out of the Address textbox?

I am using the MVVM coding pattern so would prefer to **avoid** using events.

Comment: Share the Validation.ErrorTemplate

Comment: Validation really shouldn't be done solely in the UI.  Implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in your models and you won't have this issue.  Besides, validation is a function of your business logic, not the UI, so it breaks MVVM.